# Strange execlp behavior

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I can't understand why the exec in the parent process print after the child functions.

For example, see this code:

```
if(fork()) {
     // parent
     execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", 0);
     exit(0);
} else {
    // child
    printf("\nChild stuffs...\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Child stuffs
..................
... ls command ...
```

Why "Child stuffs" is being printed before the exec? I don't have wait() or something similar and just can't figure it out...

Every ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why would you expect it to happen the other way round?

Comment: Why not? If I change the execlp function with printf("Parent print test") it will be printed before "Child stuffs"

Comment: @NicoleGrefder See my answer. And there is no guarantee that the parent's `printf` will be executed first, either. It typically so happens because the parent is already being executed while the child still needs to wait to be given a time slice by the scheduler.

Comment: That explains a lot...Thanks @user4815162342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee in which order the operating system scheduler will run the child and the parent process, which have equal priority. In your case one can suspect that the child output is printed first because it takes some time to execute an external program, whereas the `printf` is executed (and flushed, if line buffered) almost immediately.

If you move the `execlp` to the child, I would expect the parent to be more likely to display output first.

Comment: I was thinking that the parent process has a bigger priority than the children ones...Is there a official doc for more info?

Comment: @NicoleGrefder Generally, unless you've written code to make it do something differently, I believe the child process inherits it's initial priority from the parent. There may be some minor adjustment to it, but I'm not sure. However, the amount of work required by `exec*()` to set up a new process is significant, so especially on modern multi-core systems, the child will have ample opportunity to run before the parent is ready to run the new process...